# CakePHP form not posting

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I am working on a page that can update the sales agent on a specific order.
I made the list of options and a dropdown list is created.

Heres in the controller:

```
    $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
    $this->set("order",$order);

    if ($this->request->is("post")) {
        if($this->Order->save($this->request->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash("Sales Agent Updated");
        }
    }
```

Heres the view:

```
   echo $this->Form->create("Order");
        echo $this->Form->input("OrderID"); 
        echo $this->Form->input("UserID");
        echo $this->Form->submit("Submit");
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

When I submit the data, it appears that the data is saved, (the flash message is set).

However, when I then preset the fields with data that is already in the database, all the sudden it doesn't even post. (I put a debug after the reques->is("post) condition which doesnt show up after I submit).

```
    $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
    $this->set("order",$order);

    if ($this->request->is("post")) {
        if($this->Order->save($this->request->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash("Sales Agent Updated");
        }
    } 

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $order;
    }
```

The input fields are correctly pre filled, but now the form doesn't even post.

Does anybody know whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `it doesn't even post` - so what does happen? Check what requests your browser is submitting - i.e. the network tab in your brower's debug tools.

Comment: it posts but the controller doesn't recognize it

Comment: Not helpful, what does that mean? Please read the rest of my first comment.

Comment: It runs the post function and data is sent to the server but the "if" statement in the controller says it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your controller code to:

```
$order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
$this->set("order",$order);

if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if($this->Order->save($this->request->data)) {
       $this->Session->setFlash("Sales Agent Updated");
    }
}
```

Now put a debug after the `reques->is('post')` condition which will show what you need to show.

Comment: [Not true](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L314), were it the case, the code in the answer wouldn't change anything as it won't be a PUT request either (browsers do not submit PUT requests).

Comment: if so, then you have some other issue out there. show us the controller and view.

Comment: I am not the OP - you'll understand my comments to the question given that, assuming a cakephp form is actually being used, it would be a post requests.